# ICacheManager not working as intended inside ISingletonDependency implementation

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I have developed a custom search provider `CustomIndexProvider` implementing `IIndexProvider` and suppressing `Lucene.Services.LuceneIndexProvider`. For some reason, the CacheManager always executes the implementation inside the AcquireContext method and it does not cache.

```
 var mappingsFound = this.m_cacheManager.Get(cacheKey, ctx =>
            {
                ////Logic goes here
                return true/false;
            });
```

Whats going wrong with my implementation?

Am I affected by this issue https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/448781?

**FYI:**

1. `CustomIndexProvider` gets invoked from `DefaultProcessingEngine.Execute`. I create a `IIndexingTaskManager.CreateUpdateIndexTask` task whenever there is a need to update my index.
2. I also found `CustomIndexProvider` getting created for every task, even though it is inheriting `ISingletonDependency`.

Comment: Could you post the implementation?

Comment: @martinbc Please take a look at the updated question. May be the issue is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that would cause this behavior is if your cacheKey value is different on each call to this code.